# Cron expression with Fixed Delay

Tags: cron

I want to write a Cron expression which runs with a fixed Delay (runs the command > then fixed delay > runs the command > fixed delay ...) of say 5 minutes. Is there a way to write a cron expression for this?

Comment: Cron is OK if you want to run job EVERY 5 minutes. You can't rely to run with precise delay

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to test your expressions:
[crontab.guru 5 * * * *](https://crontab.guru/#5_*_*_*_*)

Or if you use Spring for your application then you could use [@Scheduled](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) annotation where are fixedDelay property

Comment: You can't rely on `cron` for FIXED delay. If cron is scheduled for 10:00 it may run in ANY second from 10:00:00 to 10:00:59